# Mule Studio- Getting exception while Testing connection in to salesforce with valid credentials

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I'm following [Connect with Salesforce Example](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Connect+with+Salesforce+Example#ConnectwithSalesforceExample-Assumptions). While testing connection after filling the required credentials in salseforce global element properties, I'm getting the following exception :

```
Test connection failed: Failed to send request to https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/28.0
org.mule.api.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/28.0
at org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceConnector.reconnect(SalesforceConnector.java:384)
at org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceConnector.connect(SalesforceConnector.java:344)
at org.mule.modules.salesforce.connectivity.SalesforceConnectorConnectionFactory.makeObject(SalesforceConnectorConnectionFactory.java:54)
at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1179)
at org.mule.modules.salesforce.connectivity.SalesforceConnectorConnectionManager.acquireConnection(SalesforceConnectorConnectionManager.java:473)
at org.mule.modules.salesforce.connectivity.SalesforceConnectorConnectionManager.test(SalesforceConnectorConnectionManager.java:532)
at org.mule.tooling.metadata.api.utils.ConnectionTester.internalTestConnection(ConnectionTester.java:70)
at org.mule.tooling.metadata.api.utils.ConnectionTester.testConnectionFor(ConnectionTester.java:92)
at org.mule.tooling.messageflow.action.TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction$1$1.run(TestConnectorConnectionFromMuleConfigAction.java:65)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Failed to send request to https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/28.0
at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:121)
at com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.login(PartnerConnection.java:844)
at org.mule.modules.salesforce.SalesforceConnector.reconnect(SalesforceConnector.java:363)
... 9 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectRaw(JdkHttpTransport.java:136)
at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectLocal(JdkHttpTransport.java:100)
at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connectLocal(JdkHttpTransport.java:95)
at com.sforce.ws.transport.JdkHttpTransport.connect(JdkHttpTransport.java:91)
at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:95)
... 11 more
     Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 28 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
... 34 more
```

The xml representation of flow looks something like given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper"
xmlns:sfdc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file      http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc/current/mule-    sfdc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-   beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
 http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
<sfdc:config name="Salesforce" username="myemail@gmail.com"
    password="password" doc:name="Salesforce" securityToken="urMWdsxXP5gJuw7QBaa02TEstk">
    <sfdc:connection-pooling-profile
        initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ONE" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW" />
</sfdc:config>
<data-mapper:config name="datamapper_grf"
    transformationGraphPath="datamapper.grf" doc:name="DataMapper" />
<flow name="Contacts_to_SFDC" doc:name="Contacts_to_SFDC"
    doc:description="Upload a csv file of contact information into Salesforce as new contacts.">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="src/test/resources/input"
        moveToDirectory="src/test/resources/output" pollingFrequency="10000"
        responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File Input" />
    <data-mapper:transform config-ref="datamapper_grf"
        doc:name="DataMapper" />
    <sfdc:create config-ref="Salesforce" type="Contact"
        doc:name="Salesforce">
        <sfdc:objects ref="#[payload]" />
    </sfdc:create>
</flow>
```

Kindly provide the solution. I'm pretty new in mule esb. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you perhaps using https with self-signed certificates somewhere?

Comment: @AntonKupias No. I'm not using self-signed certificates anywhere.

Comment: Your flow looks ok to me, and this error means that the Salesforce SSL certificate can not be validated. A quite common case is, that you are using an https connector with a custom truststore to validate self-signed certs somewhere else in the Mule app, and the Salesforce connector then uses that connector implicitly. If that is not the case, it could be due to a proxy, cache, etc mechanism in your network, a problem with the Java version, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. To connect to salesforce we need install the salesforce cloud connecter. Please click [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Installing+Connectors) to install the Connectors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Mule4, upgrade the connector to the latest version in the pom.xml file like so (example with latest version of Salesfor:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-salesforce-connector</artifactId>
            <version>9.7.8</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
```